# Get dynamic value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have two collections:

```
cc.tabGeneralValuesCollection = [{label: 'Creation Date', name: 'CreationDate', direction: 'asc', type: 'DATETIME'},    
                            {label: 'Modifier', name: 'Modifier', direction: 'asc', type: 'STRING'},
                            {label: 'Subject', name: 'Subject', direction: 'asc', type: 'STRING'}]; 

cc.tabPropertiesValuesCollection = [{label: 'Group Permission', name: 'GroupPermission', direction: 'asc', type: 'DATETIME'},   
                        {label: 'World Permission', name: 'WorldPermission', direction: 'asc', type: 'STRING'},
                        {label: 'Object ID', name: 'ObjectID', direction: 'asc', type: 'STRING'},
                        {label: 'ACL Object Name', name: 'ACLObjectName', direction: 'asc', type: 'STRING'}];
```

I have to dynamically specify which collection to use in `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="col in {{selectedTab}}">                
    <span><strong>{{col.label}}</strong></span>         
</div>
```

The variable `selectedTab` has the collection name for ex: "tabGeneralValuesCollection".

How to get this to work?

Comment: Please use the correct tags for your questions.

Comment: assign the object to `$scope.selectedTab` and access that as `ng-repeat="col in selectedTab"`

Answer (score 0):

if the `selectedTab` is your $scope object, then please try this

```
ng-repeat="col in selectedTab.tabGeneralValuesCollection"
```

But I am not sure what you mean `cc` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `this` keyword:

```
<div ng-repeat="col in this[selectedTab]">                
    <span><strong>{{col.label}}</strong></span>         
</div>
```